# Oracle sql query returning all of the values instead limiting the values

Tags: oracle

full disclosure this is part of a homework question but I have tried 6 different versions and I am stuck.
I am trying for find 1 manager every time the query runs. I.e I put the department id in and 1 name pops out. currently, I get all the names, multiple times.  I have  tried a nesting with an '=' not nesting, union, intersection, etc.  I can get the manager id with a basic query, I just can't get the name.  the current version looks like this:

```
select e.ename
from .emp e
where d.managerid in (select unique  d.managerid
                      from  works w, .dept d, emp e1
where d.did=1 and e1.eid=w.eid and d.did=w.did );
```

I realize its probably a really basic mistake that I am not seeing - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what do you mean get 1 menager any time. are it should be different menagers any time or the same?

Lest go throw your query:

1. you select all empolyes from table `emp` where manager_id in next query dataset
2. You get all managers for `dep=1`. The rest of tables and conditions are not influent on result dataset.

I theing `did` is primary key for table `dept`, If so your query may be rewritten to

```
select e.ename
from emp e
where d.managerid in (select unique  d.managerid
                      from  dept d
                      where d.did=1);
```

but this query return to you all emploees and not manager from dept=1
and if you need a manager. you should get emploee who is a manager. If `eid` is primary key of employee, and `managerid` is `id` from employee table you need something like:

```
select e.ename
from emp e
where e1.eid in (select unique  d.managerid
                      from  dept d
                      where d.did=1);
```